# 3 checkbox to update parameters differently

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement

I have a series of if statements to determine `location.href` parameters. I have never set up something like this before.

I want `throughput=`, `userNum=`, and `conEff=` to update as parameters in the URL. but for some reason, my userNum breaks the JS.

Here is my example:

```js
function goPBFour(event) {
  //something wrong with number of users updating the url
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  const userNum = formData.get("userNum");

  if (document.querySelector("input[name=throughput]").checked) {
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=user]").checked) {
      if (document.querySelector("input[name=conEff]").checked) {
        window.location.href = "evalportalb4.html" + location.search + "&throughput=true" + "&userNum=" + userNum + "&conEff=true";
      } else {
        window.location.href = "evalportalb4.html" + location.search + "&throughput=true" + "&userNum=" + userNum;
      }
    } else if (document.querySelector("input[name=conEff]").checked) {
      window.location.href = "evalportalb4.html" + location.search + "&throughput=true" + "&conEff=true";
    }
  } else if (document.querySelector("input[name=user]").checked) {
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=conEff]").checked) {
      window.location.href = "evalportalb4.html" + location.search + "&userNum=" + userNum + "&conEff=true";
    } else {
      window.location.href = "evalportalb4.html" + location.search + "&userNum=" + userNum;
    }
  } else if (document.querySelector("input[name=conEff]").checked) {
    window.location.href = "evalportalb4.html" + location.search + "&conEff=true";
  } else {
    window.location.href = "evalportalb4.html" + location.search;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="goPBFour(event)" method="get">
  <div id="pBFContainer" class="container">
    <div id="bodyFOption1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="throughput" value="yes" />Would you like to test the user experience throughput?
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyFOption2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="yes" onsubmit="goPBFour(event)" />Would you like to test capacity performance (concurrent users)?<br /> How many Users:<input type="number" id="numberUsers" size="3" name="userNum" placeholder="2" min="2"
        max="12" disabled required/> (Evaluate limits 2-12 users)
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyFOption3"><input type="checkbox" name="conEff" value="yes" />Would you like to test connection efficiency?</div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="subButton" value="Next..." />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="evalportalp1.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does *my userNum breaks the JS* mean? The `userNum` field is disabled and therefor `formData.get("userNum")` will return `null`.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams. Also store the 3 inputs in 3 local variables instead of calling `querySelector` repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues with your js, I made it somewhat simpler using less repetition

```js
function goPBFour(event) {
    //something wrong with number of users updating the url
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    const userNum = formData.get("userNum");

    let new_link = "evalportalb4.html" + window.location.search;

    if (document.querySelector("input[name=throughput]").checked) {
      new_link += "&throughput=true";
    }
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=user]").checked) {
      new_link += "&userNum=" + userNum;
    }
    if (document.querySelector("input[name=conEff]").checked) {
      new_link += "&conEff=true";
    }

    window.location.href = new_link;
}
```

---

There was a missing `</div>` and I moved the `<script></script>` to the inside of `<body>`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="goPBFour(event)" method="get">
      <div id="pBFContainer" class="container">
        <div id="bodyFOption1">
          <input type="checkbox" name="throughput" value="yes" />Would you like to test the user experience throughput?
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div id="bodyFOption2">
          <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="yes" onsubmit="goPBFour(event)" />Would you like to test capacity performance (concurrent users)?<br />
          How many Users:<input type="number" id="numberUsers" size="3" name="userNum" placeholder="2" min="2" max="12" disabled required/> (Evaluate limits 2-12 users)
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div id="bodyFOption3"><input type="checkbox" name="conEff" value="yes" />Would you like to test connection efficiency?</div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="subButton" value="Next..." />
       </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="evalportalp1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

While reading about `location.href`, I came about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location, maybe it would be better to use `location.replace()`?

Comment: i was told to be able to use the browser's back button. if I use replace I wouldn't be able to. sorry for not including that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues, I tried to rewrite it. This is where I am

Your logic is overcomplicated, AND not DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

The more I looked at this, I wondered why not just have the form?

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  const userNum = document.getElementById("numberUsers").value;
  let loc = "evalportalb4.html" + location.search;
  const throughput = document.querySelector("input[name=throughput]").checked;
  const userChecked = document.querySelector("input[name=user]").checked;
  const conEff = document.querySelector("input[name=conEff]").checked;

  if (userChecked) loc += "&userNum=" + userNum;
  if (throughput)  loc += "&throughput=true"
  if (conEff)      loc += "&conEff=true";
  alert(loc); // for debugging
  event.action = loc; // go to the URL
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm" method="get">
  <div id="pBFContainer" class="container">
    <div id="bodyFOption1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="throughput" value="yes" />Would you like to test the user experience throughput?
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyFOption2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="yes" />Would you like to test capacity performance (concurrent users)?<br /> How many Users:<input type="number" id="numberUsers" size="3" name="userNum" placeholder="2" min="2" max="12" disabled required/>      (Evaluate limits 2-12 users)
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyFOption3"><input type="checkbox" name="conEff" value="yes" />Would you like to test connection efficiency?</div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="subButton" value="Next..." />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="evalportalp1.js"></script>
```

Just the form should work if you remove the disabled on the select

```html
<form id="myForm" method="get" action="evalportalb4.html"
  <div id="pBFContainer" class="container">
    <div id="bodyFOption1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="throughput" value="yes" />Would you like to test the user experience throughput?
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyFOption2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="yes" />Would you like to test capacity performance (concurrent users)?<br /> How many Users:<input type="number" size="3" name="userNum" placeholder="2" min="2" max="12" required/>      (Evaluate limits 2-12 users)
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyFOption3"><input type="checkbox" name="conEff" value="yes" />Would you like to test connection efficiency?</div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="subButton" value="Next..." />
</form>
```

Comment: oh i see what you mean.

Comment: I had to remove  the disabled on the select though

Answer (score 1):

You can make this significantly easier and dynamic by combining the `FormData` with an `URLSearchParams` object.

In your example `FormData` extracts all the values from the form and does that in a smart way by omitting inputs that are either `disabled` or not `checked`, so you can already use that instead of checking every individual input.

Get the current URL params by passing `location.search` to a new `URLSearchParams` instance. Then loop over the `FormData` object and pass every key and value to the `URLSearchParams` object. The result should be the current params in the URL overwritten by the values from the form.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  
  // Overwrite the params with values from the form.
  for (const [key, value] of formData) {
    params.set(key, value);
  }
  
  // Construct a new URL with the params.
  const url = new URL(location.origin);
  url.pathname = '/evalportalb4.html';
  url.search = params;
  
  // location.href = url;
  console.log(url);
});

// Enabling and disabling of number of users field.
const testUserPerformance = document.querySelector('#testUserPerformance');
const numberOfUsers = document.querySelector('#numberOfUsers');
testUserPerformance.addEventListener('change', event => {
  numberOfUsers.disabled = !event.target.checked;
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 38px; }
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="throughput" value="yes" />
      Would you like to test the user experience throughput?
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label>
      <input id="testUserPerformance" type="checkbox" name="user" value="yes" />
      Would you like to test capacity performance (concurrent users)?
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label>
      How many Users:
      <input id="numberOfUsers" type="number" id="numberUsers" size="3" name="userNum" placeholder="2" min="2" max="12" disabled required/>
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="conEff" value="yes" />
      Would you like to test connection efficiency?
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```